# Angular delegate focus to host

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm attempting to implement a combo box with an `input` and `button`.  The styling for focus should make these elements appear cohesive so I'm attempting to delegate the focus to the host, but it doesn't seem to work.

Template:

```
<input #input alloy class="alloy-combobox-input" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="filterOptions($event.target.value)" >
<button #button alloy toolbar class="alloy-combobox-button" [alloyMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <alloy-icon icon="caret" orientation="down"></alloy-icon>
</button>
```

Focus:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.focusMonitor.monitor(this.el);
    this.focusMonitor.monitor(this.button).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubsribe)).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focusMonitor.focusVia(this.el, origin);
    });
    this.focusMonitor.monitor(this.input).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubsribe)).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focusMonitor.focusVia(this.el, origin);
    });
  }
```

I'll get a cdk-focus on the `input` when I click in it, but it won't forward the focus to the component host `alloy-combobox`.

What would be a good way to coordinate the focal effects of the `input` and `button` so they look like a single element?

Comment: Could you put the button and input in a wrapper div, and style that when the input receives focus (otherwise "hiding" the focus styling on the wrapped elements with border: none or something)?

Comment: I think we still end up with a one-direction-only styling issue with the button which should have the same borders.

Comment: That's just a matter of styling though, and, you could just use a div with a click event instead of a button (which for all intents and purposes is more or less what a button typically is). If you style the wrapper, and turn off the style of the input and button (border none etc), I'm pretty sure you'd get what you want.You could also "bounce" the focus of the internal elements to the wrapper (if an internal element becomes focused, reset the focus to the wrapper, or just ignore the focus altogether).

Comment: The issue I ran into with styling via the host was that `input:focus + button` selects the button, and `input + button:focus` also selects the button.  Can't select up via button focus state.

The latter is what I'd like to do.  Simply delegate focus up to the host.

Comment: so did you use that solution or not based on focusMonitor ?